# How can I solve for the Wronskian $W(x)$ in terms of $p(x)$ in this scenario?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

I am currently working through some past exam papers, and have been struggling to answer the following question. Unfortunately, the "mark-scheme" for this paper simply says 'bookwork' in place of a solution to this question...

> For a second order linear ODE of the form
>   $$
> y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = 0
> $$
>   we have the rule that
>   $$
> W'(x) + p(x) W(x) = 0
> $$
>   Solve the above for $W(x)$, in terms of $p(x)$, if $y_1(0) = 1$, $y_1 ' (0) = 0$ and $y_2 (0) = 0$, $y_2 ' (0) = 1$.

Comment: But  the Wronskian  $W(x)$ in this equation is $W'(x) + p(x) W(x) = 0$ !

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I shall amend the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard technique for solving differential equations.  It is called *separation of variables*.

You start off with the equation
$$
\frac{dW}{dx}+pW=0
$$

*Separate* the variables $x$ and $W$ to rearrange this into:
$$
\frac{1}{W}dW=-p\;dx
$$
and integrate from $0$ to $x$:
$$
\int_0^x\frac{1}{W}dW=-\int_0^xp\;dt
$$
which gives you
$$
\log(W(x)) - \log(W(0)) = -\int_0^xp(t)\;dt
$$
You can now use your initial conditions to compute $W(0)$ and finish the question.

Comment: It's wrong! You omit a $W$.

Comment: Is it not $\int_0^x \frac{W'}{W} dx = - \int_0^x p(x) dx$?

Comment: @DCooper That equation is correct, but it doesn't help you solve the problem.  You need to separate the variables, as in my answer, or use an alternative method such as the integrating factor method.